# Python Plotly: zoom box focus with mutliple axes

Tags: python, plotly

I'm creating a graph with double X and double Y axis. When using the zoom box, this only acts on one of the traces. How can I change the focus of the zoom box tool?

It seems to focus on the last trace/axes combination added. In the example below, using the zoom box changes the range of second axis pair (x2, y2). How can I have the zoom box focus on x1, y1. I could add a radio button to chooose a trace, but how do I assign that to the zoom box tool?

Example code:

```
x1 = [1,20]
y1 = [1,10]

x2 = [1,20]
y2 = [1,20]


layout = go.Layout(
    xaxis=XAxis(
        title="XAxis1"
    ),
    xaxis2 = XAxis(
        title="XAxis2",
        overlaying='x', 
        side='top',
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        title="YAxis1",
        range=[0,20]
    ),
    yaxis2=dict(
        title="YAxis2",
        range=[0,20],
        side='right'
    ),
)


# Create figure with secondary x-axis
fig = go.Figure(layout=layout)


fig.add_trace(
    go.Scattergl(x=x1,
                 y=y1,
                 name=f'Trace 1'),
)


fig.add_trace(
    go.Scattergl(x=x2,
                 y=y2,
                 name=f'Trace 2',
                 xaxis='x2',
                 yaxis='y2')
)

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `overlaying="y"` on `yaxis2`.

```py
layout = go.Layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        title="XAxis1"
    ),
    xaxis2 = dict(
        title="XAxis2",
        overlaying='x', 
        side='top',
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        title="YAxis1",
        range=[0,20]
    ),
    yaxis2=dict(
        title="YAxis2",
        range=[0,20],
        side='right',
        overlaying="y",
    ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks!

For clarity to others: this makes the zoom box act on all axes at the same time.

This obviously then also allows to change the overlay properties dynamically to change the zoom box action effect.